# Trapezoid, find the sides

Tags: geometry

I have a right tangential trapezoid.
I know the radius of the circle inscripted and the perimeter of the trapezoid. How can I find the sides?

Comment: Is this a general question, or do you have specific values in mind?

Comment: I just need a formula, or better, an explanation, values are not important. =)

Comment: Why don't you check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_trapezoid#Right_tangential_trapezoid)? It has all necessary information!

Comment: Nice, I'm Italian, so I forgot to check the English Wiki. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to put in a system these two formulas:
$$
\bigg \{
\begin{array}{rl}
r=\frac{ab}{a+b} \\
P=2(a+b) \\
\end{array}
$$